# Google Plus Login API not working correctly

Tags: google-plus

Here is the [**`demo`**](https://google-developers.appspot.com/+/demos/signin_demo_49872349874373) of Google plus sign in button using **`OAuth 2.0`**.

I want to ask that, I extracted the client id and used it in my code for authentication. Going by the rule it should not work as I do not have the correct JavaScript origin for Google's API access ( which I am presuming to be there server and not localhost). Had Google set it to localhost, only then my authentication should work. I want to know why is it working? I just have their Client Id that's it.